# Lining up div blocks in columns with no gaps/rows

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid-layout

I have a bunch of boxes/blocks in a 3 column layout. The boxes use style like `float: left, width: 33%`, but they vary in height.

How do I make it possible so they will always fill in the gaps between the column "rows" (so Panel 4 will be right under Panel 1 with no gaps in between).

Example:

```
<style>
.testpanel { width: 33%; border: 1px solid black; float:left;}
</style>
<div class="testpanel">
    Panel 1
</div>
<div class="testpanel">
    Long Panel 1
    <br /><br /><br />
</div>
<div class="testpanel">
    Long Panel 2
    <br /><br /><br />
</div>
<div class="testpanel">
    Panel 4
</div>
```

There's always a gap between Panel 1 and Panel 4 that I want closed. Is it possible to do this at all in CSS without using some js library like http://gridster.net/ ?

I know how to this in a static layout (by populating the contents per column), but I will be generating/deleting the panels dynamically, so I don't want to tie them to a specific column.

Bootstrap version: http://jsfiddle.net/WhKLj/1/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: @ajc: the intent is to not have gaps between a box and another below it. So it's almost like stacking them by columns, but dynamically.

Comment: you mean you want the `panel4` to go up and touch the bottom of `panel1`?

Comment: @King King: Correct. Basically wondering if a pinterest or gridster layout is possible in CSS only (no JS).

Comment: For anyone curious, I finally found the answer using this library: http://salvattore.com/

Answer (score 0):

your html isnt the right way to do the pinterest kind of layout.
instead of using float:left to each individual element
use three column divs

HTML:

```
<div class="column" id="left">
    <div class="testpanel"></div>
    <div class="testpanel"></div>
    <div class="testpanel"></div>
</div>
<div class="column" id="center">
    <div class="testpanel"></div>
    <div class="testpanel"></div>
    <div class="testpanel"></div>
</div>    <div class="column" id="right">
    <div class="testpanel"></div>
    <div class="testpanel"></div>
    <div class="testpanel"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column{
  float:left;
}
.testpanel{
  margin-bottom::10px;
}
```

this would do but the problem is u have to use javascript/jquery to add new div.testpanels to each of the columns.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't specify the columns because I need them to be dynamic. So when I delete/remove some panels, others will fill in the gaps. 

Also, I only have about 5-6 panels by default (this is not for a large content layout like pinterest). If I use the column style as you suggested and delete all the panels in mid column, it will look weird.

Comment: I inspected pinterest layout, and I begin to see that this might not be possible to do in CSS alone. All the boxes in pinterest are arranged using `position: absolute` and coordinate positioning.